# DUDA Android-Hacer funciones booleanas

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una función y quiero que me devuelva true o false.
Yo quiero que mi programa retorne true cuando la matriz[pos] tenga un numero superior a 27 y false cuando no lo haga.Podríais ayudarme, y explicarme como hago para sacar true o false.

```
public boolean matriz(int matri[]) {
    //Creo array de matrices aleatorio
    int i = 10 + (int) Math.round(10 * Math.random());
    int matriz[] = new int[i];

    Log.i("POSICIONES", String.valueOf(matriz.length));

    int pos=0;
    tx1.setText("");
    tx2.setText("");
    // Recorro array de matrices
    for (pos = 0; pos < matriz.length; pos++) {
       //Cada posicion del array almacenara un valor aleatorio;
        matriz[pos] = (int) Math.round(30 * Math.random());
        //El valor aletorio es mayor que 27. Devuelve true, sino devuelve 
        false
        if (matriz[pos] > 27) {
            tx1.setText(tx1.getText() + "" + matriz[pos] + ", ");
        } else {
            tx2.setText(tx2.getText() + "" + matriz[pos] + ", ");
        }
    }
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias crear una variable booleana y almacenar el retorno alli para el caso que necesitas que se cumpla y lo retornas al final del programa.

```
public boolean matriz(int matri[]) {

 // variable almacenar retorno
 boolean retorno=false;

//Creo array de matrices aleatorio
int i = 10 + (int) Math.round(10 * Math.random());
int matriz[] = new int[i];

Log.i("POSICIONES", String.valueOf(matriz.length));

int pos=0;
tx1.setText("");
tx2.setText("");
// Recorro array de matrices
for (pos = 0; pos < matriz.length; pos++) {
   //Cada posicion del array almacenara un valor aleatorio;
    matriz[pos] = (int) Math.round(30 * Math.random());
    /**El valor aletorio es mayor que 27. Devuelve true, sino devuelve 
    false**/
    if (matriz[pos] > 27) {
        tx1.setText(tx1.getText() + "" + matriz[pos] + ", ");
        retorno=true;
    } else {
        tx2.setText(tx2.getText() + "" + matriz[pos] + ", ");
        retorno=false;
    }
}

 return retorno;
```

}

Comment: Al principio tenía dudas de si era eso, ya que me daba siempre true, pero ahora me da trues y falses, pero igualmente gracias hermano ;)

Comment: es que no entiendo lo que te aparece, ahi con eso deberia darte true o false en el programa ya que se almacena en la variable retorno y solo se devuelve ese valor